# AngularJSでmousedownとtouchstartが発火しない

Tags: javascript, angularjs

以下のコードでmousedownとtouchstartが発火しません。
touchmoveも発火したりしなかったりで安定しません。
何が原因でしょうか？
mouseupとtouchendは発火しています。

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$http', '$interval', '$swipe', '$location', function($scope, $resource, $http, $interval, $swipe, $location) {
　　//省略
    $scope.timerStart = function() {
        console.log("timer start");
        time_timer = $interval(function() {
        }, 1000);
        console.log(time_timer);
    };
    $scope.touchMove = function() {
        $interval.cancel(time_timer);
    };
    $scope.touchEnd = function() {
        console.log("touch end");
        $scope.timerStart();
    };
$scope.timerStart();
}])
.directive('timeClick', function() {
    return {
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$http', '$interval',
            function($scope, $element, $attrs, $http, $interval) {
                var isTap, isTapped;
                $element.bind('click', function() {
                    if(!isTapped) {
                        return $scope.$apply($attrs['hogeClick']);
                    }
                });
                $element.bind('touchstart', function() {
                    console.log('touch start');
                    return isTap = true;
                });
                $element.bind('mousedown', function() {
                    console.log('mouse down');
                    return isTap = true;
                });
                $element.bind('touchmove', function() {
                    $scope.touchMove();
                    return isTap = false;
                });
                return $element.bind('touchend mouseup', function() {
                    $scope.touchEnd();
                    if(isTap) {
                        isTapped = true;
                        return $scope.$apply($attrs['hogeClick'], $element);
                    }
                });
            }
        ]}
    }
);
```

Comment: 解決しました。
Bootstrapのライブラリを使用していた関係で、追加されたDOMにイベントを追加しないと駄目でした。

そのため、外部から以下のコードでAngularJSのメソッドにアクセスして解決しました。

angular.element(document.getElementById('hoge')).scope().touchStart();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**この部分はコード貼り付けミスの指摘だけだったので削除しました**

---

## 追記 :18:03

ためしてみましたが、イベントは起きているように思います。
以下がサンプル。

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngTouch']);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$http', '$interval', '$swipe', '$location', function($scope, $resource, $http, $interval, $swipe, $location) {
    //省略
    $scope.eventtrace = [];

    $scope.timerStart = function() {
      console.log("timer start");
      time_timer = $interval(function() {}, 1000);
      console.log(time_timer);
    };
    $scope.touchMove = function() {
      $interval.cancel(time_timer);
    };
    $scope.touchEnd = function() {
      console.log("touch end");
      $scope.timerStart();
    };
    $scope.timerStart();
  }])
  .directive('timeClick', function() {
    return {
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$http', '$interval',
        function($scope, $element, $attrs, $http, $interval) {
          var isTap, isTapped;
          $element.bind('click', function() {
            if (!isTapped) {
              return $scope.$apply($attrs['hogeClick']);
            }
          });
          $element.bind('touchstart', function() {
            console.log('touch start');
            $scope.eventtrace.push("touch start");
            return isTap = true;
          });
          $element.bind('mousedown', function() {
            console.log('mouse down');
            $scope.eventtrace.push("mousedown");
            return isTap = true;
          });
          $element.bind('touchmove', function() {
            $scope.touchMove();
            $scope.eventtrace.push("touch move");
            return isTap = false;
          });
          return $element.bind('touchend mouseup', function() {
            $scope.touchEnd();
            if (isTap) {
              isTapped = true;
              return $scope.$apply($attrs['hogeClick'], $element);
            }
          });
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl" style="font-size:14pt;">
    <div time-click>[ touch me ]</div>
    <p>
      {{eventtrace}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

なお、配列にはmousedownとtouchstartとtouchmoveしかpushしてないのでそれ以外のイベントは画面には出てきません。

Windows上のChromeと、iPhone 6 (iOS 8)のsafariで試しました。
Windows上ではWebStormのDebugでも見ましたが特にエラーはないです。

touch moveが安定しているかまでは判断できませんが、一応発動はしているように見えました。

ただ、一つだけ気になるとすれば、貼り付けたコードの`//省略` の手前に全角スペースがあるぐらいですけど、ここはまぁ行ごと元々のコードにはないのでしょうから関係はなさそうですね。

Comment: すみません、コピペの時に余計なコードが混じったようです。
編集しておきました。
ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: こちらでも動作が確認できました。
恐らくですが、他のここに出していないHTMLかjavascriptのコードが弊害を出しているような気がします。
全体のコードを調査することにしました。